# how to find performance issues in C# application

Tags: c#, performance

My C# application does a lot of ClientHttp calls on many Task/Async/Await methods inside Paraller.ForEach block, but it performance is not perfect (application seems to slow down in time). How to investigate where are issues. What tools should be used? How to use these tools like Profiler?

External links are welcome.

How my application works:
It downloads images and zipped images from backend, unzip them if needed and saves them in directories on local hard drive. It downlaods about 7GB of images.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Analyze menu (profiler)

Comment: Slowing down in time may possibly be a memory leak, or perhaps memory fragmentation.  You could have a look at those possibilities first.  If you are using a database, then you might need to re-index it and clear out deleted records regularly, those issues can slow down database access.

Comment: @Kilanny any good link about how to use it?

Comment: @ rossum: I added more details how my app works.

Comment: @P.K. simple google search yields as first result: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check this samples from msdn ...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: Yes, good. He needs also to check if he is app is making web requests on main thread instead of background.

Comment: I have many returning `async Task<T> X()` methods so they are background thread, right? But what it means?